# CSS menu starts from center and continues to the right

Tags: css

I have the following css menu, which starts from the middle and continues on to the right. Meaning that cream color bar continues on to the end of the page. Tried searching, but wasn't able to find a solution, perhaps not possible?
[image]
The HTML I got:

```
<header>
                    <nav class="splash-menu">
                        <ul class="splash-nav">
                            <li class="why-splash">Why us</li>
                            <li class="dealer-splash">Dealer Login</li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </nav>
                </header>
```

The CSS:

```
.splash-nav{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #0B3543;
}
.splash-nav li{
    float: left;
    height: 60px;
}
.splash-menu{
    float:left;
   width:100%;
   overflow:hidden;
   position:relative;
}
.splash-menu ul {
   clear:left;
   float:left;
   list-style:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   position:relative;
   left:75%;
   text-align:center;
}
.splash-menu ul li {
   display:block;
   float:left;
   list-style:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   position:relative;
   right:50%;
}
.splash-menu ul li a {
   display:block;
   margin:0 0 0 1px;
   padding:3px 10px;
   text-decoration:none;
   line-height:1.3em;
}
```

Comment: And more importantly, what are you trying to accomplish? It's hard to give a right answer if we have to guess what "right" is.

Comment: I added the Code I've got. I want a ribbon kind of menu, so the menu items "Home" and "Why us" are in the middle of the page with fancy colors, then the ribbon continues until the end of the page to the right. We don't see the end of it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the image I would suggest that rather than it starting from the middle, the menu is aligned to the right of the element holding it.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp